# how to refactor this jquery code to count checked options and set message accordingly without having to repeat same code

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I have several groups of checkboxes, with a "none of the above" option (input value='none') for each group. I have a working code which is repeated for each group to count and set a message accordingly. (note: the "none of the above" option *toggle with the other options* is being taken care of elsewhere as a built-in feature in the form - a Drupal Webform)

I'm struggling (as a newbie who learns on the go) to shorten the code by avoiding repeating the same code for each group. I need to somehow set the part of the class as variable and re-use it in the count and message inputs for each group.

```
<fieldset>
Group 1 Qs:
<div class="eg1">
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q1"> Text here 1
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q2"> Text here 2
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q3"> Text here 3
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q4"> Text here 4
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="none"> none of the above
  </div>

</div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset>
Group 2 Qs:
<div class="sth1">
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q1"> Text here 1
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q2"> Text here 2
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q3"> Text here 3
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q4"> Text here 4
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="none"> none of the above
  </div>

</div>
</fieldset>
:: RESULTS :: <br>
<div class="results-wrapper" style="font-weight: bold;"> Group 1 Results:
  <div>
    Count a: <input class="eg1_count" name="eg1_count" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
  <div>
    Message a: <input class="eg1_msg" name="eg1_msg" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="results-wrapper" style="font-weight: bold;"> Group 2 Results:
  <div>
    Count a: <input class="sth1_count" name="sth1_count" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
  <div>
    Message a: <input class="sth1_msg" name="sth1_msg" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
```

and this is the jQuery code for the first 2 groups:

```
    $('input[class^=adftg][value^=q]').change(function() {
      var a = $('input[class^=adftg][value^=q]:checked').length
      $('.eg1_count').val(a);
      var msg = '0';
      var msgbox = $('.eg1_msg')
    
      if (a < 3 && a > 0) {
        var msg = 'msg for 1 or 2 count in group EG1';
      } else if (a >= 3) {
        var msg = 'msg for 3 more count in group EG1';
      } else {
        var msg = ('msg for none selected');
      }
      (msgbox).val(msg);
    });
    // if "none of the above" is checked set the count to '0' and give a message
    $('input[class^=adftg][value=none]').change(function() {
      $('.eg1_count').val(0);
      $('.eg1_msg').val('msg for none of the above in group EG1');
    });
// second group
    $('input[class^=adftg][value^=q]').change(function() {
      var a = $('input[class^=adftg][value^=q]:checked').length
      $('.sth1_count').val(a);
      var msg = '0';
      var msgbox = $('.sth1_msg')
    
      if (a < 3 && a > 0) {
        var msg = 'msg for 1 or 2 count in group STH1';
      } else if (a >= 3) {
        var msg = 'msg for 3 more count in group STH1';
      } else {
        var msg = ('msg for none selected');
      }
      (msgbox).val(msg);
    });

//  if "none of the above" is checked set the count to '0' and give a message
    $('input[class^=adftg][value=none]').change(function() {
      $('.sth1_count').val(0);
      $('.sth1_msg').val('msg for none of the above in group STH1');
    });
```

**EDIT:** In light of the first 2 answers kindly shared by @Swati and @cars10m and their ideas (new to me) to approach the task, please note that my form is long and more complicated than I tried to demo above. The results-wrapper for each questions set is separated from the actual questions groups by many other divs. I can move it each to follow its related group of questions but I'd rather not. I was expecting a solution based on my first jquery code but refabricated so I don't have to repeat the same code again and again. However, the idea of being able to select by div containers is very appealing and may give me more flexibility to re-use the code elsewhere for similar type of questions (where lots of counting of checked checkboxes or radios over pages). I am open to any suggestions for best plan to re-structure my form ( a long Drupal multipage Webform) in a way to make life easier and code simpler but more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `<div>` tag around your checkboxes so that we can use `$(this).closest('div')` to find checkboxes and other inputs inside that div only at a time .In below code i have added repeating code to some `function` and pass the value of `length` to get required `message` and have added that message to required inputs .

**Demo code** :

```js
//on change of checkbox
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
var name=  $(this).closest('div').attr('class')
  //if value is none 
  if ($(this).val() == "none") {
    //add reuqired count and message to input box
    $(this).closest('div').find("input[name='count']").val(0);
    $(this).closest('div').find("input[name='message']").val('msg for none of the above in group '+name);

  } else {
    //get slectore
    var selector = $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    //get length
    var length = selector.filter(':checked').length;
    var msg = evaluate(length); //call function
    //add value to required inputs
    $(this).closest('div').find("input[name='message']").val(msg+""+name)
    $(this).closest('div').find("input[name='count']").val(length)

  }
});

function evaluate(a) {
  if (a < 3 && a > 0) {
    var msg = 'msg for 1 or 2 count in group ';
  } else if (a >= 3) {
    var msg = 'msg for 3 more count in group ';
  } else {
    var msg = ('msg for none selected');
  }

  return msg;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--added div-->
<div class="EG1">
  <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q1"> Text here 1 <br>
  <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q2"> Text here 2 <br>
  <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q3"> Text here 3 <br>
  <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q4"> Text here 4 <br>
  <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="none"> none of the above <br> Count a: 
  <!--add name="count"-->
  <input class="eg1_count" name="count" value="" size="30" maxlength="50"><br><br> Message a: <input class="eg1_msg" name="message" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  <hr>
</div>
<div class="STH1">
  <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q1"> Text here 1 <br>
  <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q2"> Text here 2 <br>
  <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q3"> Text here 3 <br>
  <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q4"> Text here 4 <br>
  <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="none"> none of the above <br> Count b: <input class="sth1_count" name="count" value="" size="30" maxlength="50"><br><br> Message b: <input class="sth1_msg" name="message" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

**Update 1** :

In below demo code i have directly selected the inputs and added value to it because we are already having class `eg1` and `sth1` so we can use this here .

**Demo Code** :

```js
//on change of checkbox
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var name = $(this).closest('div').parent().attr('class')
  var classes= $(this).attr('class') //get class of checkbox
  //if value is none 
  if ($(this).val() == "none") {
   $("."+classes).not(this).prop('checked', false);//uncheck other
    $("input[name=" + name + "_count]").val(0);
    $("input[name=" + name + "_msg]").val('msg for none of the above in group ' + name);
  } else {
    var selector = $(this).closest('div').parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var length = selector.filter(':checked').length;
    var msg = evaluate(length); 
    //add value to required inputs
    $("input[name='" + name + "_msg']").val(msg + " " + name)
    $("input[name='" + name + "_count']").val(length)

  }
});

function evaluate(a) {
  if (a < 3 && a > 0) {
    var msg = 'msg for 1 or 2 count in group ';
  } else if (a >= 3) {
    var msg = 'msg for 3 more count in group ';
  } else {
    var msg = ('msg for none selected');
  }

  return msg;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  Group 1 Qs:
  <div class="eg1">
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q1"> Text here 1
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q2"> Text here 2
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q3"> Text here 3
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q4"> Text here 4
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="none"> none of the above
    </div>

  </div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset>
  Group 2 Qs:
  <div class="sth1">
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q1"> Text here 1
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q2"> Text here 2
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q3"> Text here 3
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q4"> Text here 4
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="none"> none of the above
    </div>

  </div>
</fieldset>
:: RESULTS :: <br>
<div class="results-wrapper" style="font-weight: bold;"> Group 1 Results:
  <div>
    Count a: <input class="eg1_count" name="eg1_count" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
  <div>
    Message a: <input class="eg1_msg" name="eg1_msg" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="results-wrapper" style="font-weight: bold;"> Group 2 Results:
  <div>
    Count a: <input class="sth1_count" name="sth1_count" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
  <div>
    Message a: <input class="sth1_msg" name="sth1_msg" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Comment: thank you but: 1- since you're not selecting by classes this may not work well since I have many other checkboxes sets I don't want to target. Plz correct me if wrong. 2- the message is not respecting the group of each (I need to mention to which group the message belongs to in each message e.g. EG1, STH1 ....etc).

Comment: for 2 .See updated code . Also for 1 you can put that checkboxes around some outer div  and change your selector to `$('.classwheretodo input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {` so it will be call checkboxes under that div .

Comment: Thanks Swati, I'll test it as per your additions and accept your answer if all worked

Comment: Swati, that didn't work in my case because each input is in a separate div (as shown in my updated question). Otherwise, I love the way you approached it and I'm sure I'm gonna make use of it elsewhere in my form (a lengthy webform).

Comment: @Adam888 please check `update 1` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Wonderful, many thanks Swati. I had to tweak it a little bit and make minor changes to my form but it ended up exactly as I wanted. I removed the line to "uncheck other" because it seems it was conflicting with the built-in toggle. I also added .attr('class').split(' ', 1)[0]  to first two lines because my classes come in an array and want to only select first one. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2:**
OK, here it is. I adjusted my answer again to deal with the updated and more realistic HTML structure. Please check again.

I made the following changes:

- first I create two jQuery objects `Q` (all questions) and `A` (all answers)
- in the event handler I identify `res` on the basis that the answer will have *the same internal position* in the jQuery object as the question in its jQuery object:
  `let res=A.eq(Q.index(div[0])).find('input');`

The rest of the script then works as before.

```js
const Q=$('fieldset > div');      // all question divs
const A=$('div.results-wrapper'); // all answer divs
//on change of checkbox
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  const div=$(this).closest('div').parent();
  div.find('[type=checkbox][value'+(this.value=="none"?'!':'')+'=none]')
     .prop('checked',false); // mimic a radio-button-loke behaviour
  let cnt=div.find('[type=checkbox][value!=none]:checked').length;
  let res=A.eq(Q.index(div[0])).find('input');
  if (true) { res[0].value=cnt;
  res[1].value=
   (cnt? cnt<3 ? 'Fewer than 3'
               : '3 or more'
       : 'No') 
   +' boxes checked.' ;
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- changed again, after OP provided update -->
<fieldset>
Group 1 Qs:
<div class="eg1">
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q1"> Text here 1
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q2"> Text here 2
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q3"> Text here 3
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="q4"> Text here 4
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_eg1" type="checkbox" value="none"> none of the above
  </div>

</div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset>
Group 2 Qs:
<div class="sth1">
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q1"> Text here 1
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q2"> Text here 2
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q3"> Text here 3
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="q4"> Text here 4
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="adftg_sth1" type="checkbox" value="none"> none of the above
  </div>

</div>
</fieldset>
:: RESULTS :: <br>
<div class="results-wrapper" style="font-weight: bold;"> Group 1 Results:
  <div>
    Count a: <input class="eg1_count" name="eg1_count" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
  <div>
    Message a: <input class="eg1_msg" name="eg1_msg" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="results-wrapper" style="font-weight: bold;"> Group 2 Results:
  <div>
    Count a: <input class="sth1_count" name="sth1_count" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
  <div>
    Message a: <input class="sth1_msg" name="sth1_msg" value="" size="30" maxlength="50">
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
```

I first handle the logic that *either* one or more text options can be checked *or* the "none" option. In both cases all checkmarks of the "other" nature in the current section must be removed.

After that I simply count the `:checked` checkboxes and put the results into the count and message input-fields. There is no need for your `evaluate()` function since this can easily be done in a one-liner with two ternary operators (`condition ? whentrue : whenfalse`).

The line

```
div.find('[type=checkbox][value'+(this.value=="none"?'!':'')+'=none]')
```

deserves a closer look: depending on whether the currently clicked checkbox has a value `=="none"` I add an `'!'` or an `''` (empty string) to the selector string which will then be:

```
'[type=checkbox][value!=none]'  // for this.value=="none"
'[type=checkbox][value=none]'   // for this.value!="none"
```

Comment: Thanks cars10m , great tips for me to learn more but, like I said re first answer, not working because my inputs are wrapped in divs as shown in my updated question. The class ("name" var) to get each group's name in the relevant message.

Comment: strangely, this code while works here it doesn't work with my actual form where it gives me a " TypeError: res[0] is undefined " when I check in my FF console! The checkboxes don't check when I click on them and only the "none of the above" does. BTW, the "none of the above" state toggle with other checkboxes is being taken care of elsewhere as a built-in feature (it's a Drupal Webform).

Comment: Admittedly, the selector for finding `res` is not that simple and might break if your document structure is not *exactly the same* as the one in the above snippet. Try and apply it in several stages and see what you get in `res`. I . e. do: `res=div.nextAll(".results-wrapper:eq(0)")` then `res=div.nextAll(".results-wrapper:eq(0)").find('input')` and have a look at the `length` attribute of `res`. It must allways be `>0`.

Comment: Yes indeed my form is more complicated than I tried to demo in my question where I was expecting a solution using css selectors mostly, sth similar to my code but refabricated (if possible). The ".results-wrapper" divs (one for each Qs group) e.g. are separated from the questions by may divs of other groups of qs and I had to move one of them to just below the Qs set just to test your code. Using your method although looks great, short and efficient otherwise but maybe problematic in my case!

Comment: I update my question with further info and html further for a much closer demo of real case.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the amazing help all the way and all things I learnt from your approach, cars10m. Swati's answer more fully solved my case problem, though (inc. using the groups var name in the msg). With your code, for some reason only the last "A" input is being updated whenever any other "Q" changes from any other group of "Q" !  Plus, I had to remove the line to "mimic a radio-button-loke behaviour"  because the code wouldn't work with it (no checkbox is clickable except the none of the above) as it seems to be conflicting with the built-in toggle and no need for it anyways in my case.